# how to remove dataType "int32" from the swagger definition for an integer attribute

Tags: swagger, jsonschema

I am generating from swagger through annotations. One of the response model attribute is int. Json schema shows it as 
"totalResults":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32"
            } 
I would like to remove the format from the swagger.

As per swagger specification doc the integer can have 3 formats "-", "int32" and "int64"
[Swagger definition snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzZd5.png)

Is there anyway to remove the format or force format type "-". I tried @ApiModelProperty annotation which does show option for dataType but nothing for format. I do not know how to set the format.

Comment: What is your motivation in invalidating the OpenAPI definition? Do you want to create a JSON schema?

Comment: I am trying to use dredd to do contract testing. Dredd complains about int32. The error get it with int is : unknown format "int32" is used in schema at path

Comment: Are you using the Swagger 1.5.x (i.e. OpenAPI 2.0) or the newer Swagger 2.x (OpenAPI 3.0), for which the Dredd support is still "experimental"? – independent of that: you are providing the OpenAPI definition as input to Dredd and you know what exactly causes the issue. How about simply iterating through the whole schema and removing the `"format": "int32"` yourself before providing it to Dredd?

Comment: I am using swagger2.x. Removing int32 is a workaround. I tried removing it manually to check whether it fixes the issue. Do you suggest using hook code to remove format=int32?

Comment: So now found out that this issue is with Dredd version 13, Reverted dredd to v12 and that solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like dredd v13 has this issue. Downgrading dredd to version 12 resolved the format int32 issue. Now Dredd accepts the given swagger 2 specification.